# Format-preserving encryption with Crypto++

Tags: encryption, crypto++

is it possible to perform FPE with the Crypto++ library?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to encrypt?

Comment: It is an unique id containing date, time and some integers

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to perform FPE with the Crypto++ library?

Well, it depends on how you define Format Preserving Encryption.

In [A Synopsis of Format-Preserving Encryption](http://www.voltage.com/wp-content/uploads/UCSD_Rogaway_Synopsis_Format_Preserving_Encyption-1.pdf), Phillip Rogaway stated: "... it is my view that the cryptographic literature already contains good solutions for FPE but that, at least until quite recently, the ideas were scattered about, not widely known, and not cohesively described."

If you are talking about Bellare, Spies and Rogaway's FFX mode of operation proposed to NIST circa 2010, then the answer is no. Crypto++ does not have FFX mode.